# Flutter doesn't launch the app after adding OneSignal. OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension is unknown to FrontBoard

Tags: flutter, onesignal

Flutter can't launch my application after adding onesignal to my app. I've followed this [guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup#section-2-adding-the-notification-service-extension-ios-). After managing all problems I got this one.

When I do `flutter run` I see the error below:

```
ProcessException: Process "/usr/bin/xcrun" exited abnormally:
<your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension: -1

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "<your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application
"<your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "<your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" is unknown to
        FrontBoard.
        Application "<your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension" is unknown to FrontBoard.
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch 26CD3C41-B2F7-4B59-9360-97C9688ABE38
  <your-app>.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

What I've tried:

- Relaunching my emulator
- Erasing all data on the emulator
- Cleaning the build folder

OneSignal version: 1.0.5

```
flutter --version
Flutter 1.1.8 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 985ccb6d14 (6 weeks ago) • 2019-01-08 13:45:55 -0800
Engine • revision 7112b72cc2
Tools • Dart 2.1.1 (build 2.1.1-dev.0.1 ec86471ccc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `iOS/Runner/Info.plist` and set your `bundleId` in the section `CFBundleIdentifier`

1. Your bundle id is here. Copy it.
   [image]
2. Paste `bundleId` into `CFBundleIdentifier` in the `info.plist`
   [image]

Do the same actions in the `iOS/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension/Info.plist`

I hope this helps. At least it worked for me.

**Note:
BundleId of the OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension has a slightly different id. Check it in xcode before adding it to the .plist of OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.**

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue.

```
ProcessException: ProcessException: Process "/usr/bin/xcrun" exited abnormally:
Failed to install the requested application
The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion.
Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleVersion.
  Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 552DF0B1-4A65-46FE-8125-C2B37F3005DC/example/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
```